# How to use your own domain www.yourdomain.com to serve Google Cloud Storage content

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have been using Google Cloud Storage succesfully to serve the videos and images for the webservice using Django. However, the links for the images must include the following prefix :

```
'https://storage.googleapis.com/' + GS_BUCKET_NAME + "/"
```

How can I serve the content directy from my service name ? ( for instance "www.mydomain.com/content/" rather than "https://storage.googleapis.com/".

Update :

I have updated CNAME on Google Domains as below :

```
www.supereye.co.uk CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com
```

yet via supereye.co.uk/dog.png I am still seeing the following output :

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

Also, one question, while using Django url directing, how will it decide for a following link, which is a file on GCS bucket :

```
www.supereye.co.uk/dog.png
```

if this an API from my Django App or this is a link to Google Storage Bucket instead ?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website)?

Comment: Also read this one: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#https

Comment: I am facing "NoSuchBucket" error, what could be the suggestion here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what needs to be done here :

Create a bucket : production2.supereye.co.uk

Then in CNAME use :

production2 CNAME supereye.co.uk

And now you can server Django App on "supereye.co.uk"

While serving production2 bucket of Google Cloud Storage on production2.supereye.co.uk